# What is the difference between Marxism and Leninism?

Tags: ideology, communism, marxism, leninism

I am really intrigued by the idea of communism, especially Marxism and Leninism. But I am struggling to find the differences between these two communist ideologies. Both of them seem to try to establish a social order where everyone is equal and where everyone is treated as equal despite their social and economic status.

So what are the differences between the two? And if you may, can you tell me which Communist ideology demands the equal distribution of wealth among all the people?